# beautifulsoup python class parse

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get product_list by parsing a website

```
soup = bs(product_list_get.text, 'html.parser')
productlist = soup.find_all('td',{'class':'txtCode'})
```

some part of result is as follows

```
[<td class="txtCode"><a class="txtLink eProductDetail _product_code" href="/disp/admin/shop1/product/ProductRegister?product_no=42" product_no="42" target="_blank" title="새창 열림">P00000BQ</a></td>, <td class="txtCode"><a class="txtLink eProductDetail _product_code" href="/disp/admin/shop1/product/ProductRegister?product_no=41" product_no="41" target="_blank" title="새창 열림">P00000BP</a></td>
```

what i want to get is list of product_no

so the optimal result would be

```
[42,41]
```

I tried

```
productlist = soup.find_all('td',{'class':'txtCode'}).get('product_no')
```

but the result is

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

can anyone kindly guide me how to deal with this?

Comment: Like the error message tells you (and your example result shows you, and the name of the method indicates), `find_all` gives you multiple results. You can't `.get` from a `ResultSet`; presumably you want the `product_no` for *each* result, so try iterating over the results.

Answer (score 1):

The method [`find_all`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) returns list of Tag elements. So your code `productlist = soup.find_all('td',{'class':'txtCode'})` returns a list of `<td>` elements. You want to get the attribute `number_no` of inner `<a>` element for each `<td>` you found.

Iterate over the `productlist` and access the `number_no`.

```
productlist = soup.find_all('td', {'class':'txtCode'})
product_nos = [int(p.find('a').get('product_no')) for p in productlist]
```

---

Alternatively, you can find `<a>` elements, which contain attribute `product_no`.

```
results = soup.find_all('a', {'product_no':True})
product_nos = [int(r.get('product_no')) for r in results]
```

Answer (score 1):

`product_no` is contained inside `href`, so you need to extract `href`. Then you can use regex to match `product_no`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

lists = [
"""<td class="txtCode"><a class="txtLink eProductDetail _product_code" href="/disp/admin/shop1/product/ProductRegister?product_no=42" product_no="42" target="_blank" title="새창 열림">P00000BQ</a></td>""", 
"""<td class="txtCode"><a class="txtLink eProductDetail _product_code" href="/disp/admin/shop1/product/ProductRegister?product_no=41" product_no="41" target="_blank" title="새창 열림">P00000BP</a></td>"""]

for each in lists:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(each,"lxml")
    href = soup.a.get("href")
    product_no = re.search(r"(?<=product_no=)\w+",href).group(0)
    print(product_no)
#42
#41
```